Error: "string too large to encode using UTF-8 written instead as 'STRING_TOO_LARGE'" after updating Android API level from 33 to 34
After updating the Android API level from 33 (Android 13) to 34 (Android 14), I have updated all required dependencies and configurations. However, upon syncing, cleaning, and rebuilding the project, I encountered the following error:
"string too large to encode using UTF-8 written instead as 'STRING_TOO_LARGE'."
Steps to Reproduce:

Upgrade the project's Android API level from 33 to 34 (targeting Android 14).
Update all dependencies to be compatible with the new API level.
Sync, clean, and rebuild the project in Android Studio.
The error appears during the build process.

Expected Behavior: The project should successfully build without encoding issues.
Actual Behavior: During the build process, the following error occurs:
App should build succesfully
Config :
android {
namespace 'com.My app'
compileSdkVersion 34
buildToolsVersion "34.0.0"
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a'
        universalApk true
    }
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my app"
    minSdkVersion 28
    compileSdk 34
    targetSdkVersion 34
    versionCode 32
    versionName "1.8.1"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

minimal reproducible example :
"I encountered the issue mentioned above after updating the Gradle version and cleaning and rebuilding the project. However, the project was working fine with the same string length earlier."
I tried updating the long string in different parts but its not working.
https://i.sstatic.net/65Yyc5iB.png

Please edit your question and provide more details like your Gradle config and the full error message.

Please [edit] and provide a [mre] so that we can see for ourselves.

I have updated the details of config and reproducible example
